# Ingesting Confluent Kafka stream as SingleStore pipeline - Failed to look up or compile schema id

Tags: singlestore

I'm trying to understand the SingleStore platform by ingesting a Confluent Cloud Kafka topic. I'm getting this runtime error and not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I confirmed that I can ingest the stream using the confluent_kafka consumer but when I test the pipeline using these instructions (https://www.singlestore.com/spaces/ingest-data-from-confluent-cloud-kafka/) I'm getting this error:

`%%sql TEST PIPELINE  {{S2_DATABASE_NAME}}.{{S2_PIPELINE_NAME}} LIMIT 1;`

RuntimeError: (singlestoredb.exceptions.OperationalError) 2458: Leaf Error (node-326dd458-6cc0-4391-94ca-dbcbb27f6047-master-0.svc-326dd458-6cc0-4391-94ca-dbcbb27f6047:3306): Leaf Error (localhost:3306): Leaf Error (node-326dd458-6cc0-4391-b058-d2ccf6ac8c55-leaf-ag1-0.svc-326dd458-6cc0-4391-94ca-dbcbb27f6047:3306): Failed to look up or compile schema id 100003 of record 1 from registry. Forwarded error:"REST request failed (code 401): {"error_code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}".
[SQL: TEST PIPELINE  confluent_kafka.kafka_consumer_pipeline LIMIT 1;]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
If you need help solving this issue, send us a message: https://ploomber.io/community

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm trying to consume a data generator AVRO test source.

I tried resetting the API keys for Confluent API and schema registry. I confirmed the schema matched the AVRO format

Comment: i figured this out.  Apparently I was using an old URL for the schema registry endpoint